# generic массивы и new T()

Tags: java, generics

Java документация гласит, что джинерики работают с помощью механизма "стирания", т.е. это:

```
class Test<T> {
    T foo;
    T bar;

    Test(T o) {

    }
}
```

Будет превращено во время компиляции в это:

```
class Test {
    Object foo;
    Object bar;

    Test(Object o) {

    }
}
```

Ведь так? Хорошо, тогда почему такой код не работает?

```
class Test<T> {
    T[] foo;
    T bar;

    Test(T o) {
        foo = new T[5];
        bar = new T();
    }
}
```

Ведь, по идеи, этот код во время компиляции станет таким:

```
class Test {
    Object[] foo;
    Object bar;

    Test(Object o) {
        foo = new Object[5];
        bar = new Object();
    }
}
```

И никаких проблем быть не должно, но они есть. Почему так происходит?

Comment: На самом деле инстанцировать T можно, но через рефлексию

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Массивы отличаются от обобщённых типов в двух важных аспектах.
>   Во-первых, массивы ковариантны (covariant). Это жуткое слово значит
>   просто, что если Sub является подтипом Super, тогда тип массива Sub[]
>   является подтипом Supeг[]. Средства обобщённого программирования,
>   напротив, инвариантны (invariant): для любых двух отдельных типов
>   Туре1 и Туре2 тип List не является ни подтипом, ни супертипом
>   для List [JLS, 4.10; Naftalin07, 2.5]. Вы можете подумать, что
>   это недостаток средств обобщённого программирования, но можно
>   поспорить, что недостатком, напротив, обладают именно массивы.
>
> Вторым важным отличием массивов от обобщённых типов является то, что
>   массивы реифицированы (reified) [JLS, 4.7]. Это значит, что массивы
>   знают и проверяют тип своих элементов при выполнении. Как выше было
>   сказано, если вы попытаетесь сохранить String в массив Long, вы
>   получите исключение ArrayStoreException. Обобщённые типы, напротив,
>   реализуются стиранием (erasure) [JLS, 4.6]. Это значит, что они
>   проверяют свои ограничения типов только на этапе компиляции и затем
>   выбрасывают (или стирают) информацию о типах элементов при выполнении.
>   Стирание позволяет обобщённым типам легко взаимодействовать со старым
>   кодом, который не использует средства обобщённого программирования.
>
> По причине этих фундаментальных различий массивы и обобщённые типы не
>   могут применяться одновременно. Например, нельзя создавать массив
>   обобщённых типов, параметризованных типов или параметров типа. Ни одно
>   из этих выражений создания массивов не является разрешённым: new
>   List[], new List[], new E[]. Все выражения приведут к
>   ошибкам создания обобщённых массивов на этапе компиляции. Почему
>   нельзя создавать обобщённые массивы? Потому что это небезопасно. Если
>   бы это было разрешено, приведение типов, генерируемое компилятором в
>   правильно написанной программе, могло бы вызвать исключение
>   ClassCastException. Это бы нарушило фундаментальные гарантии, которые
>   даёт система обобщённых типов.

© Joshua Bloch "Effective Java", глава 5, статья 25

Comment: Спасибо! На счет массивов понял, но что на счет new T()?

Comment: @WenSiL обобщённые типы добавлены в Java чтобы увеличить типобезопасность и избавить от рантайм ошибок, а не добавить новых, позволяя инстанцировать `Object` там где ожидается более конкретный тип.

Comment: Теперь точно все понял.

Answer (score 1):

`T` - это тип. Ключевое слово `new` вызывает конструктор класса. Но у типов нет ни методов, ни констукторов.

Ради интереса представим что `new T()` работало бы. Пусть у нас будет дженерик метод вызывающий конструктор внутри, и пусть будет класс `User` с нестандартным конструктором:

```
class User {
    String name;

    User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = Test.<User>genericFoo();

        System.out.println(user.name);
    }

    static <T> T  genericFoo() {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Получается что дженерик метод вызывает конструктор который не существует в природе!

---

К моему сожалению, в Джаве порой трудно различить типы и классы. Например, вызов статического метода класса выглядит так, будто метод вызывается из типа - `Test.<User>genericFoo()`. Но типы не имеют методов.

У типов и классов есть свои иерархии. Типы там связаны между собой через сабтайпинг, классы связаны через наследование. Часто эти иерархии похожи.

Рассмотрим типичный случай:

[image: 1]

```
interface Animal {
    default String makeVoice() {
        return "Grrrr";
    }
}

class Dog implements Animal { }
class Cat implements Animal { }
```

1) Благодаря наследованию мы можем вызвать методы полученные по наследству.

2) Благодаря сабтайпингу мы можем положить "котов" в переменную для "животных".

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String voiсe = new Dog().makeVoice();

        Cat cat = new Cat();
        Animal animal = cat;
    }
}
```

---

Другой пример, когда иерархия типов не совпадает с наследованием:

```
public class Test3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog[] dogs = {};
        Animal[] animals = dogs;

        LinkedList<Dog> dogsList = new LinkedList<Dog>();
        LinkedList<Animal> animalsList = dogsList; // тут не компилируется
    }
}
```

Массив собак никогда не наследовал массив животных, но в иерархии типов массив собак - является подтипом массива животных. Благодаря чему компилятор разрешает нам класть массив собак в переменную для массива животных. Как писали другом ответе - это свойство называется **ковариантность**.

Листы (как и остальные дженерик классы) - **инвариантны**, т.е. так как лист собак не наследует лист животных, то и в иерархии типов - они не связаны. А значит присваивать их компилятор не разрешает.

Надеюсь этот опус немного помог различать типы и классы.